# Magento 2 : collection filter error : Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Illegal state

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, exception

I am having problem with collection filter

I am using event **catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after** to add collection limitations

In the observer i am using below code to apply filter.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('manufacturer','218');
    return $this;
}
```

It is throwing Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Illegal state

From

```
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
```

there is code that check $this->searchResult

```
 if ($this->searchResult !== null) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Illegal state');
    }
```

check exception trace here

https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/23zw

How to fix this if i remove **throw new \RuntimeException('Illegal state');** then it is working but it's not a good idea right ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply all filters prior a collection is loaded. If a search result is not null it means the collection is actually loaded. At least you need to check if it is loaded or not by means of the collection method "isLoaded".

Comment: thanks, it works!

Comment: i am facing the similar issue. how can i fix it ? i am using this "$collection->addFieldToFilter('price',['from' => $pricerange[0], 'to' => $pricerange[1]]); "